# How to make nginx-proxy generate a self-signed certificate for every Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, openssl, reverse-proxy, self-signed

**On my VPS,** I can have my Docker containers automatically listen to a domain on port 443 and retrieve https certificates for those domains with [`nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), [`docker-gen`](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) and [`docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion).

**On my localhost,** for development purposes, I'm using `nginx-proxy` and `docker-gen` in conjunction with *dnsmasq* to make every container listen to a domain ending in `.test` on port 80.

It would be useful for certain aspects of development to be able to test local sites on https as well. Many browser features are blocked on http domains.

Is it possible to do something similar to the letsencrypt method for servers, but use self-signed sertificates signed with a self-trusted root authority, which I can import into Google Chrome?